# JSP EL tag not correctly parsed?

Tags: java, jsp, el

In my Servlet I do this :

```
request.setAttribute("header", "templateheaderv1");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/master.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In my master.jsp page I do this :

```
<jsp:include page="/template/${header}.jsp" />
```

What I should get is this :

```
<jsp:include page="/template/templateheaderv1.jsp"/>
```

But what I get is this :

```
<jsp:include page="/template/javax.servlet.jsp.el.ImplicitObjectELResolver$ImplicitObjects$7@6e4eeaaf.jsp"/>
```

Which obviously throws a FileNotFoundException.

The header of my web.xml is this :

```
<web-app 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
```

Which should suffice to parse EL variables, no?

I'm running this containerless with Jetty 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable name is colliding with one of the [implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043) (the HTTP header map.) Change the name to something else.

Comment: You were right :) Thanks. Do you perhaps have a link with an overview of the occupied attribute names?

I will accept your answer in two minutes btw :)

Comment: @Pieter-Jan: He already provided a link where the implicit objects are listed.

Comment: Lol maybe he edited it or I looked over it. in any case thanks :)